# GridView android studio - onHover?

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, android-gridview

I would like to implements kind of onHover to my gridView.
This is my current code:

```
    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = findViewById(R.id.emoji_grid);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AfterChooseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("test", id);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

            }
        });
```

That gave me the following view:

[image]

So I want that the background of each cell in the grid will be change when the mouse is on it.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` has no listener for hover events. I suggest you switch to using a `RecyclerView` and call `setOnHoverListener` on the view holders. The following links should help:

- [Create a List with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)
- [How to replace gridView to RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441790/how-to-replace-gridview-to-recyclerview)